# Interline in lstlisting

Tags: line-spacing

how could I reduce interline space in lstlisting?

```
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\listingsfont]
```

Does not work for me and it says:

Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex" The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX. You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex". For immediate help type H .

But I am not sure I want to change that. Are there other ways?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with `listings`. If you load `fontspec`, then you must use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Can you show a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved putting before and after the listing

```
\begin{spacing}{0.5}
...
\end{spacing}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `fontspec`. Define suitably `\listingsfont`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\listingsfont}{\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

Normal interline space
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\listingsfont]
abc
def
ghi
\end{lstlisting}

Shortened interline space
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\linespread{0.8}\listingsfont]
abc
def
ghi
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But that does not work. I get the fatal error above quoted

Comment: @Klapaucius Without a minimal example showing what you're doing, how can you expect more than a generic answer? How are you defining `\listingsfont`? Of course, if you load `fontspec` you *must* compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

Comment: But whit the way I found it works even without compiling with one of those two

Comment: @Klapaucius I voted for closing, because the question is very unclear. If you're satisfied with a kludge, good for you; but I'd much prefer a real answer.

Comment: for me we can close it, np